# Can a Windows Installer perform logic like a normal application

Tags: c++, winapi, batch-file, installation, windows-installer

**Can a Windows Installer perform logic like a normal application?**

For example: I am creating an installer that installs plugin files to a 3rd Party Application's directory on the C drive. But the destination directory will be different if the user has an old version of the 3rd Party Application.

So the installer needs to determine what version of the 3rd Party Application is on the C drive. If its the new version I install the plugin files to C://Program Files//3rdPartyApplication// and if its the old I install to C://3rdPartyApplication//

*So can a windows installer perform logic and if not can it run batch files that can do this?*

Comment: are you using Wix? : http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you tell me how you can know what is the version of the 3rd Party Application, and what is "old version" and what is "new", I will show you a Batch file that do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

An "installer" is just a regular application designed to unpack its contents onto a persons hard drive, and possibly perform actions like registry modifications.

If you use a installer like install shield for example you will have to look at that installer documentation to see what it can do. Most installer applications have some sort of area to create custom scripts.

You could also build your own, it is really not very hard.

Comment: Definitely I would not recommend writing an installer application yourself: It's not that simple as it seems. You have to care for many different things which you may not event expect to happen. That's why it is advisable to use an existing installer suite which has been thoroughly tested. There are free open source suites as well as commercial alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, installer can perform logic just like regular application. From this point of view, an installer is a regular application.

How you program installer logic depends on which installer suite you use. For detecting whether an application exists in `C:\Program Files\3rdPartyApplication` or in `C:\3rdPartyApplication`, you can use [`FileSearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) element of [WiX Toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), look through Windows Installer documentation: [*Searching for Existing Applications, Files, Registry Entries or .ini File Entries*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa371564.aspx).

More sophisticated logic can be implemented by [custom actions](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm). [Custom Actions}(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066.aspx) can be written in JScript, VBScript, C/C++ (DLL or EXE; yet the EXE can't communicate to the Windows Installer session).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to give a different perspective.  Windows Installer is a declarative domain specific programming language.  It is not a Turing complete general purpose programming language.  It is not intended to be just like any other application.  It can be extended with custom actions written in general purpose programming languages such as C++/C# but it should stil follow the same declarative approach where you seperate the "how" to do something from the "what" to do.

Now to answer the second part of your question.   Windows Installer has built in searching capabilities.  Read the MSDN topics on the AppSearch standard action and related tables (AppSearch, Signature, DrLocator, CompLocator, RegLocator )    You can also put conditions on components and you can set directory destinations dynamically  so yes, there are ways of doing what you want to do.

It would require much more information to explain exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows Installer can perform logic like a normal application.

You can use the WiX Toolset, as suggested by Alexey to get the job done.

You can use the FileSearch element ( http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) to check for the existence of files or the RegistrySearch element ( http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) in case you want to check using a registry key.

Alternatively, if the search isn't as simple as checking for a file or a registry, a Custom Action would let you write managed or unmanaged code (according to your preference) to check which version of the 3rd party application is installed.

On the basis of the result of your search, you can, at run-time, change your install directory. A Type 35 Custom Action would let you change the install directory:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx